# Can I be alerted of other app notifications

Tags: ios, notifications

I know I cant block other notifications from things like facebook or Twitter etc, but is there anyway to be notified of them, so I can manage my own content and the user doesn't miss critical information that exists on my navigation bar. I think this would be a fair compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to be notified of notifications from other apps.

Comment: Then navigation Bars are useless for anything other than navigating, what If I had some kind of stock market app with critical timing and some kind of 'cancel trade' button and a timer.. suddenly an important notification comes along showing what your friend have for his lunch and the app cant do anything about it!

Comment: So you mean you want to stop them from appearing so that none of the UI of your app gets covered?

Comment: No I just want to be notified one is coming in so I can move the content down and it doesn't get covered up

Comment: I double checked to be sure, but it seems impossible. Notification are meant to be private.

Answer (score 0):

- Your app won't get notified, while receiving other app's notification.
- Your server has to send a notification whenever you want to send.
- As per Apple documentation, it is not advisable to use the notification in critical situation. Because the delivery time may vary based on the traffic. But we don't have other options.